# Changing shape in legend ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

This is my data:

```
head(pcf)
      IID POP         PC1        PC2        PC3          PC4         PC5 shape
1 HG01113 CLM -0.00284857 0.01432160 0.01585010 -0.024035900 -0.01479180    16
2 HG01121 CLM -0.00397075 0.00928773 0.00451518 -0.003877280  0.00327456    16
3 HG01122 CLM -0.00718415 0.01118450 0.00167478  0.000797229  0.00836530    16
4 HG01124 CLM -0.00986231 0.00227199 0.00715461 -0.011777700 -0.00514219    16
5 HG01125 CLM -0.00850170 0.00826662 0.01105800 -0.010627100 -0.00627586    16
6 HG01130 CLM -0.00680245 0.01178180 0.00824017 -0.012398000 -0.00414566    16

str(pcf)
'data.frame':   6385 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ IID  : Factor w/ 6385 levels "HG01113","HG01121",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ POP  : Factor w/ 29 levels "CEU","CLM","MXL",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ PC1  : num  -0.00285 -0.00397 -0.00718 -0.00986 -0.0085 ...
 $ PC2  : num  0.01432 0.00929 0.01118 0.00227 0.00827 ...
 $ PC3  : num  0.01585 0.00452 0.00167 0.00715 0.01106 ...
 $ PC4  : num  -0.024036 -0.003877 0.000797 -0.011778 -0.010627 ...
 $ PC5  : num  -0.01479 0.00327 0.00837 -0.00514 -0.00628 ...
 $ shape: num  16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 ...
```

And I want to make a scatterplot of PC1 vs PC2 with different colors and shapes. I managed to change the colors, and the shapes on the plot. However, the legend shapes don't change? I tried change it manually with no success. I tried other answers on this website, but couldn't solve my problem. Thank you.

This works but legend shape don't mach my shape column.

```
ggplot(pcf, aes(x = PC1, y = PC2, shape = shape, color = POP)) + geom_point(size=2.5,alpha=0.8) + scale_color_manual(values=colf) +
  ggtitle("PC1 vs PC2") +theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +  scale_shape_identity()
```

I tried changing manually, but it didn't work:

```
ggplot(pcf, aes(x = PC1, y = PC2, shape = shape, color = POP)) + geom_point(size=2.5,alpha=0.8) + scale_color_manual(values=colf) +
  ggtitle("PC1 vs PC2") +theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +  scale_shape_manual(values=c(17,15,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,12))
```

Sample of data:

If I use the same function, without adding colors I can't still solve the problems with the shapes on the legend:

```
ggplot(pcf2, aes(x = PC1, y = PC2, shape = shape, color = POP)) + geom_point(size=2.5,alpha=0.8) +
  ggtitle("PC1 vs PC2") +theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +  scale_shape_identity()

pcf2 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="IID   POP PC1 PC2 PC3 PC4 PC5 shape
HG01113 CLM -0.00284857 0.0143216   0.0158501   -0.0240359  -0.0147918  16
HG01121 CLM -0.00397075 0.00928773  0.00451518  -0.00387728 0.00327456  16
HG01122 CLM -0.00718415 0.0111845   0.00167478  0.000797229 0.0083653   16
HG01124 CLM -0.00986231 0.00227199  0.00715461  -0.0117777  -0.00514219 16
HG01125 CLM -0.0085017  0.00826662  0.011058    -0.0106271  -0.00627586 16
HG01130 CLM -0.00680245 0.0117818   0.00824017  -0.012398   -0.00414566 16
HG01131 CLM -0.00652902 0.0109067   0.00998472  -0.0121705  -0.00635762 16
HG01134 CLM -0.0113558  0.00757026  0.00777452  -0.0144193  -0.00243384 16
HG01136 CLM -0.00748575 0.00859226  0.00928788  -0.0136143  -0.00756104 16
HG01137 CLM -0.001601   0.00926993  0.0126941   -0.0147104  -0.0144014  16
ZAN0140 ZAN -0.00858195 0.00409118  0.00875769  -0.0106631  -0.00546549 16
ZAN0141 ZAN -0.0115329  -0.00297351 0.00911975  -0.0126809  -0.0120499  16
ZAN0142 ZAN -0.0117186  -0.0044713  0.0101049   -0.0141045  -0.0151751  16
ZAN0143 ZAN -0.0114532  -0.00415046 0.00547798  -0.00756357 -0.00506384 16
ZAN0144 ZAN -0.0213624  -0.00843936 0.00607225  -0.00874548 -0.00393357 16
ZAN0145 ZAN -0.00409835 0.00369836  0.0101785   -0.0147436  -0.00811818 16
ZAN0146 ZAN -0.0097486  -0.00643543 0.00687725  -0.0105866  -0.00621137 16
ZAN0147 ZAN -0.00915782 0.00459452  0.00728844  -0.0122016  -0.00862952 16
ZAN0148 ZAN -0.0104426  0.0130516   0.00894079  -0.0103534  -0.000177178    16
ZAN0149 ZAN -0.0114827  -0.00395054 0.00823912  -0.0115696  -0.0121063  16
ZAN0150 ZAN -0.00608103 0.0123405   0.0102158   -0.0120628  -0.00832722 16
NA12763 CEU -0.0105495  0.0276811   -0.00224035 0.010225    0.0299631   17
NA12775 CEU -0.010177   0.0281884   -0.00250204 0.00959566  0.0306824   17
NA12776 CEU -0.0101447  0.027379    -0.00347948 0.0116001   0.0279258   17
NA12777 CEU -0.0105071  0.028844    -0.00320231 0.00978598  0.0300142   17
NA12778 CEU -0.0102704  0.0283507   -0.00261262 0.0101554   0.0299162   17
NA12812 CEU -0.0104907  0.0280414   -0.00393934 0.0107501   0.0295738   17
NA12814 CEU -0.0106704  0.0283296   -0.0030067  0.00877782  0.0298366   17
NA12815 CEU -0.0101239  0.0277695   -0.00322395 0.0111492   0.0314943   17
NA12827 CEU -0.0101015  0.0283498   -0.00298194 0.00927265  0.0291947   17
NA12828 CEU -0.0102718  0.0276927   -0.00440554 0.010354    0.0273352   17
NA12829 CEU -0.0105987  0.0276975   -0.00251459 0.00949609  0.027011    17
NA12842 CEU -0.0104375  0.0279966   -0.00427633 0.0118914   0.0311316   17
NA12843 CEU -0.0100162  0.0282866   -0.00352916 0.0122782   0.0319997   17
NA12872 CEU -0.0105538  0.027088    -0.0018147  0.0104983   0.0302558   17
NA12873 CEU -0.0103432  0.0277881   -0.00359204 0.0108997   0.0311401   17
NA12874 CEU -0.0112648  0.0279512   -0.000582816    0.00909585  0.0292212   17
NA12889 CEU -0.0107102  0.0283009   -0.00292015 0.010161    0.0269977   17
NA12890 CEU -0.0104645  0.0284091   -0.00234357 0.00891193  0.0297733   17
NA18486 YRI -0.067202   -0.0580439  -0.0103843  0.0072099   -0.0025057  18
NA18488 YRI -0.0679582  -0.0575973  -0.0099637  0.00786681  -0.00176836 18
NA18489 YRI -0.0665639  -0.0572469  -0.0104585  0.00290702  -0.00247813 18
NA18498 YRI -0.0675714  -0.0578045  -0.00714871 0.00705127  -0.000810779    18
NA18499 YRI -0.0672439  -0.0581789  -0.00975973 0.00608173  -0.00354541 18
NA18501 YRI -0.0681507  -0.0589588  -0.00955431 0.00765419  0.00182204  18
NA18502 YRI -0.0677346  -0.0585321  -0.00946384 0.00801378  0.00215776  18
NA18504 YRI -0.0674863  -0.0588057  -0.0102074  0.008341    -0.000466679    18
NA18505 YRI -0.0683932  -0.0590951  -0.00959998 0.00761924  0.00080716  18
NA18507 YRI -0.0670518  -0.0582837  -0.00794506 0.00631916  -0.00260588 18
NA18508 YRI -0.0679485  -0.0585929  -0.00827961 0.00845302  0.000591506 18
NA18510 YRI -0.0674159  -0.0584644  -0.0101846  0.0078433   0.000852638 18
NA18511 YRI -0.0670849  -0.0581807  -0.0103638  0.00851522  -0.000592863    18
NA18516 YRI -0.0687822  -0.0592477  -0.00899918 0.00443706  -0.001659   18
NA18517 YRI -0.0670035  -0.058226   -0.00876939 0.00489847  -0.00112354 18
NA18519 YRI -0.0669615  -0.0578218  -0.00695668 0.00571593  -0.00287655 18
NA18520 YRI -0.0680311  -0.0581343  -0.00911587 0.00869178  -0.00377441 18
NA18522 YRI -0.0678606  -0.0583533  -0.0103429  0.00532382  -0.000140096    18
NA18523 YRI -0.0671548  -0.0578681  -0.0116837  0.00707126  -0.00172178 18
NA18853 YRI -0.0684294  -0.0587003  -0.01088    0.0066453   0.000847722 18
NA18856 YRI -0.0668358  -0.0572994  -0.00962481 0.00882953  0.000972082 18
NA18858 YRI -0.0672418  -0.0577705  -0.0111758  0.00790765  -0.000706462    18
NA18861 YRI -0.067371   -0.0577288  -0.00911194 0.00500546  -0.00104702 18
NA18864 YRI -0.0665593  -0.0579576  -0.00921739 0.00677675  0.00126966  18
NA18865 YRI -0.068028   -0.0587356  -0.00898244 0.00833009  0.000123099 18
NA18867 YRI -0.0671763  -0.0583929  -0.00788941 0.00667197  -0.00272322 18
NA18868 YRI -0.067829   -0.05892    -0.0075401  0.00683461  -0.00272168 18
NA18870 YRI -0.0687969  -0.059312   -0.00936288 0.00699998  -0.00129002 18
NA18871 YRI -0.0685796  -0.0598433  -0.00940723 0.0053345   -0.000116678    18
NA18873 YRI -0.0671831  -0.0577216  -0.00908974 0.00755018  -0.00379051 18
NA18874 YRI -0.0670375  -0.0577672  -0.008836   0.00841137  -0.00202849 18
NA18876 YRI -0.0675866  -0.0580677  -0.00881668 0.00660232  -0.000117921    18")
```

Comment: A vector of colors. I did it manually instead of using a pallete because I had more than 12 levels.

Comment: HubertL answered your question, but to answer your subquestion: "legend shape don't mach my shape column," a useful method is to specify the `values` as a named vector.  Ex. `scale_shape_manual(values = c("16" = 16, "17" = 17, "18" = 18))`.  You can use this for color or other scales where you want to explicitly define your variables.  This produces a separate shape legend.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using `guides()` and `guide_legend()`:

```
ggplot(pcf2, aes(x = PC1, y = PC2, shape = shape, color = POP)) + geom_point(size=2.5,alpha=0.8) + 
        ggtitle("PC1 vs PC2") +theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +  scale_shape_identity() + 
        guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = tapply(pcf2$shape, pcf2$POP, mean, na.rm = TRUE))))
```

Comment: I get this error: Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, aes, value = c(17, 16, NA, NA, NA,  : 
  replacement has 29 rows, data has 4

Comment: Nope, I'm getting the same error. It's weird because I just copy the small dataset that I pasted here.

Comment: It is because as extracted from your full dataset, it has 29 factors

Comment: My data has only 12 factors.

Comment: it says POP  : Factor w/ 29 levels

Comment: @HubertL's solution works for me (+1 vote).  OP, your question sounds like you want to combine shape and color in the legend.  From a design perspective, isn't this redundant to indicate data type (POP) by both shape and color?  Especially considering you are limited in the number of shapes you can use.